# Adding columns to an existing list on Sharepoint 2010 intranet

Tags: 2010, list, column, intranet

I am trying to add two new columns to an existing list on an intranet page (on SharePoint 2010).

I've used the guidance [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2#ID0EAADAAA=2010) and seem to be able to only get so far.

I've found the list I want to add the columns to and seem to have added them. But the new columns only seem viewable under "View All Site Content. When I go back to the page where the list is on the intranet I can't see the 2 new columns I've added.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong - the only thing that doesn't look right is that the new column titles (under View All Site Content) are in red and the old columns (visible on the intranet page) are in black.

Any help or advice appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to add the new column on the page:

1. Add the newly added column in the **list view** you want to show on the page.
2. Go to the page where you added web part and click the gear icon on the upper right corner.
3. Select Edit page.
4. Edit your List Web Part.
5. Expand the Selected View and choose the view you want to use(In which you have added newly created columns).
6. Click Apply to check the outcome.
7. Click OK and save the changes

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?